# Displaying node.js output variable on canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

My node.js program's output is a series of points (x,y). What I need is to display these points on canvas (without browser) so I thought this module can work to display my points

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
const canvas = createCanvas(200, 200)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

// Write "Awesome!"
ctx.font = '30px Impact'
ctx.rotate(0.1)
ctx.fillText('Awesome!', 50, 100)
```

I installed it via npm but I can not see any canvas on my screen when I run this code. 
Does it write to a file or something?
Should I create a webserver or some other thing to see the canvas on my screen? (Sorry I am not a computer geek so this is hard for me. I am trying to do my homework and I just want to display it on a canvas without a browser.)

**Note:** I have points like {2,3}, {5,8} and so on as output of my Node.js code. I want to display these points on screen. This is the 1st problem. If I can handle this, I go to 2nd phase which is when I move my mouse point locations will be calculated and new points will be drawn. But I should first display points on my screen as in this picture.

[image: canvas]

Comment: If you just wanted to save the result, click on `createXyStream`-s on the page you linked, like [`createPNGStream()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#canvascreatepngstream), and it shows that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a browser to display a canvas. Unless I'm mistaken.

I don't think that package writes to file no.

You need a web server to use node

Could you provide a little more information? Such as what you mean when you say "screen". I am quite confused as to what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Your need a canvas for that , which requires the use of a browser. Although i feel you may be confused about the terminology. node is used to create server side instructions , if you want to edit client side/browser/canvas side behaviour you will need to use javascript which will then be interpreted by a browser.

Comment: I know it already. I am asking if I can draw these points with Node.js. I know how to draw with pure Javascript and HTML but I need to learn if I can draw those points with Node.js.

Comment: You cant draw with node no , you can pass those values to the client/javascript and draw them that way. But node is server side, meaning it doesnt really deal with visual things like this

Answer (score 0):

Try [node-gd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd) or [node-webkit](https://nwjs.io/)

**Long answer:**

Since you don't involve a browser, you cannot draw to a canvas. The term canvas in majority of JS libraries is the browser canvas.

However, you can draw the output to a [bitmap image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) and save it as a file using [node-gd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gd) package. See [examples](https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd#examples) for drawing points to a bitmap file.

Another option is to output an SVG document. But you'll need to [create an xml document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-writer), and know [basics of SVG schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12/shapes.html) to begin with.

IF you also want a GUI like an desktop application, try [node-webkit](https://nwjs.io/).

Comment: Can you please check the library I gave the link in my post? Isn't it used for a standalone canvas without the need for a browser?

Comment: @Lyrk The library seems to offer canvas API, but does not talks about actually presenting a GUI window from OS. If so, then other option is same as libGD, that is saving output to a file.